# Eliminating the Unwanted White Space Between App Bar and Sidebar Navigation

Tags: flutter, dart, drawer, appbar

I am developing a Flutter application and I've run into an issue with my layout that I'm having trouble solving. Specifically, I have a line of white space appearing between my app bar and the sidebar navigation, which I want to remove to achieve a seamless look.

Here's the structure of my application:

- I am using `AutoTabsRouter.tabBar` with three routes: HomeRoute, InvoiceRoute, and ProfileRoute.
- My `AppBar` contains a custom title and a `Row` widget as its bottom PreferredSize. The `Row` contains an IconButton for a menu and a TabBar with three tabs corresponding to my routes.
- The AppBar's flexible space is filled with a `FlexibleSpaceBar`, and I'm using a `CustomPaint` to paint the background.
- The body of my Scaffold contains a second Scaffold that includes a `NavDrawer` as a drawer and the active tab's widget as its body.

Here's my Flutter code for the same:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AutoTabsRouter.tabBar(
      routes: const [
        HomeRoute(),
        InvoiceRoute(),
        ProfileRoute(),
      ],
      builder: (context, child, controller) {
        final tabsRouter = AutoTabsRouter.of(context);
        final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
            toolbarHeight: size.height * 0.34,
            title: title(context),
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(12),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        _scaffoldKey.currentState!.isDrawerOpen
                            ? _scaffoldKey.currentState!.closeDrawer()
                            : _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
                      },
                      icon: Icon(
                        menuIcon,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: size.width * 0.85,
                    child: TabBar(
                      controller: controller,
                      tabs: [
                        tab("Home"),
                        tab("Invoice"),
                        tab("Profile"),
                      ],
                      onTap: (index) {
                        tabsRouter.setActiveIndex(index);
                      },
                      indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                      indicatorPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            centerTitle: false,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: CustomPaint(
                painter: AppBarBackground(),
                size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8305555555555556)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: Scaffold(
            key: _scaffoldKey,
            onDrawerChanged: (isOpened) => setState(() {
              if (isOpened) {
                menuIcon = Icons.close;
              } else {
                menuIcon = Icons.menu;
              }
            }),
            drawer: const NavDrawer(),
            body: GestureDetector(child: Builder(
              builder: (context) {
                if (mounted) {
                  return child;
                }
                return Container();
              },
            ), onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
              if (details.primaryVelocity! > 0) {
                controller.animateTo(controller.index - 1);
              } else if (details.primaryVelocity! < 0) {
                controller.animateTo(controller.index + 1);
              }
            }),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Despite this setup, there's an undesired white space that appears between the AppBar and the sidebar navigation. I would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction on how to remove this gap. It's noteworthy that this issue occurs even though I'm using the FlexibleSpaceBar to fill up the space in the AppBar.

I've included a screenshot here for reference:
[Gap between appbar and side drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWLIE.png)

[Full page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsoUK.png)